# IndexedDB is not working in a WebView - why?

Tags: android, android-webview, indexeddb, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams application where I need to use local storage (IndexedDB).

All works fine with the most common browsers: Chrome, Firefox but when I try to use the application with the Android app for Teams, something goes wrong: "It is necessary for the correct functioning of the app to allow access to IndexedDB".

Android Version: 10 - WebView Version: 81.0.4044.138

From my point of view is something relative to the permissions for local storage with WebView

This is my code:

```
if (window.indexedDB) {

  var request = indexedDB.open('__mydb', 2);
    request.onerror = function (event) {
      alert('It is necessary for the correct functioning of the app to allow access to IndexedDB.');
    };
    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
      mydb = event.target.result;

      try {
        console.log('Database opened, checking existence of table');
        var objectStore = mydb.transaction([tableName], 'readwrite')
          .objectStore(tableName);

        console.log('Table exists. Proceeding to save data');
        saveTokenDataIndexedDB(objectStore);

        console.log('All done, going to app');
        goToApp();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
 }
```

This is the manifest file of my Teams application:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.2/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "packageName": "XXXXXX",
  "id": "29bcd6f4-XXXXXX-4111-820b-XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version": "0.1",
  "developer": {
    "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "websiteUrl": "https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/collaboration",
    "privacyUrl": "https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/servicesagreement"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "full": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "XXXXXXXXXXXX_outline.png",
    "color": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX_color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#004578",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://{teamSiteDomain}{teamSitePath}/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest={teamSitePath}/_layouts/15/teamshostedapp.aspx%3FopenPropertyPane=true%26teams%26componentId=XXXXX-eadc-4020-XXXX-edea2c24753b%26forceLocale={locale}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "XXXXX",
      "name": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "contentUrl": "https://{teamSiteDomain}/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/_layouts/15/teamshostedapp.aspx%3Fteams%26personal%26componentId=XXXXXXXXX-eadc-4020-b4e2-XXXXXXXb%26forceLocale={locale}",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "*.login.microsoftonline.com",
    "*.sharepoint.com",
    "*.sharepoint-df.com",
    "spoppe-a.akamaihd.net",
    "spoprod-a.akamaihd.net",
    "resourceseng.blob.core.windows.net",
    "msft.spoppe.com"
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "resource": "https://{teamSiteDomain}",
    "id": "XXXXXXXX-eadc-4020-b4e2-XXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

I'm stuck with this, if somebody can give me a clue I will be grateful.

Regards

Comment: try printing out the actual error instead of your own error. the actual error has a text message in it that will give you insight into your problem. asking on stack overflow about your own error message is not likely to get a good answer.

Comment: Hi @Josh, My message is the result of the error, From my point of view it´s a great and complex question.